# C# Generic foreach over IEnumerable of unknown type

Tags: c#, foreach, collections, ienumerable

I'm trying to write a generic static function that takes an instance of an IEnumerable class, the name of a property of  and a string separator. It will loop through the instance and with each member of the instance evaluate the property, collecting the values returned in a single string spaced by the separator.

For example, if my collection class contains instances of Person and the property name is "Surname", and my separator is "', '", I might return: "Smith', 'Kleine', 'Beecham". I might then surround it in single quotes and use it as a list in SQL.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to iterate over IEnumerable. My code so far:

```
public static string EnumerableItem2Str<T>(IEnumerable<T> oItems, string cPropertyName, string cSep)
{
    string cOP = "";
            
    try
    {
        foreach (<T> oItem in oItems)
        {
            cOP += CoreHelper.GetPropertyValue(oItems, cPropertyName).ToString();
            if (oItem != oItems.Last()) cOP += cSep;
        }
        return cOP;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "";
    }
}

public static object GetPropertyValue(object o, string cPropertyName)
{
    return o.GetType().GetProperty(cPropertyName).GetValue(o, null);
}
```

I get errors on the line `foreach (<T> oItem in oItems)` the first of which is "type expected" on `<T>`.

How do I iterate over `oItems` to get each instance contained within it?

Comment: `foreach (T oItem in oItems)`. Also you probably mean to pass `oItem` into `CoreHelper.GetPropertyValue(oItems, cPropertyName)` right? Though, a func to "get" the property would be nicer than reflection

Comment: @matt - so obvious, yet so illusive. Thank you. I now get the weird error on the comparison ```(oItem != oItems.Last())```, which is ```Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'```. Odd. Any thoughts?

Comment: Since T can literally be anything, it doesn't know how to compare. Simplest is assume it'll only be a class and use the generic type constraint `where T : class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this (it does have a null propogation check so if you're using an old version of C# then you'll need to remove that question mark before the '.GetValue(i)'):

```
public static string EnumerableItem2Str<T>(IEnumerable<T> oItems, string cPropertyName, string cSep)
{
    var propertyValues = oItems
        .Select(i => i.GetType().GetProperty(cPropertyName)?.GetValue(i))
        .Where(v => v != null)
        .ToList();

    return string.Join(cSep, propertyValues);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Calum. This does exactly what I want and drops straight in. The only disadvantage of doing it this way is that constructing a list is more memory intensive that looping through the class and building the string directly, but I'm only looking at a couple of dozen items, tops. Spot on. Thanks. :)

Comment: You can remove the ToList() and it will still work as string.Join needs to take an IEnumerable. I just prefer to use ToList() so I can easily view the elements when debugging. Should only really have any performance impact if the collection is massive

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```cs
static string GetCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string separator)
{
    return String.Join(separator, items.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
}
```

Check it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rA3BnO)